# MySQL ON UPDATE CASCADE not CASCADEing

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

Suppose i have two below table:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  id bigint(20)     NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
  text text ,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE post_path (
  ancestorid bigint(20)     NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
  descendantid bigint(20)   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
  length int(11)            NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',

  PRIMARY KEY (ancestorid,descendantid),
  KEY descendantid (descendantid),

  CONSTRAINT f_post_path_ibfk_1 
    FOREIGN KEY (ancestorid) REFERENCES post (id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT f_post_path_ibfk_2 
    FOREIGN KEY (descendantid) REFERENCES post (id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And inserted these rows:

```
INSERT INTO 
    post (text)
    VALUES ('a'); #// inserted row by id=1
INSERT INTO 
    post_path (ancestorid ,descendantid ,length) 
    VALUES (1, 1, 0);
```

When i want to update post row id:

```
 UPDATE post SET id = '10' WHERE post.id =1
```

MySQL said:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (test.post_path, CONSTRAINT f_post_path_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (descendantid) REFERENCES post (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Why? what is wrong?

**Edit:**

When i inserted these rows:

```
INSERT INTO 
    post (text)
    VALUES ('b'); #// inserted row by id=2

INSERT INTO 
    post_path (ancestorid, descendantid, length)
    VALUES (1, 2, 0);
```

And updated:

```
UPDATE post SET id = '20' WHERE post.id =2
```

Mysql updated successfully both child and parent row.
so Why i can not update first post (id=1)?

Comment: your answer is in your error.

Comment: Your update statement is trying to update an auto_increment column, which you cannot do.

Comment: Hmmm didn't know you could manually update an auto_increment column like that. Even though you can, you shouldn't.

Comment: @Mike, ok. but what is the problem that i can not update post#1 but i can update post#2

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I ran your schema and queries through a test database I have access too and noticed the following; after inserting both rows to both tables, and before any updates the data looks like:

```
mysql> select * from post;
+----+------+
| id | text |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from post_path;
+------------+--------------+--------+
| ancestorid | descendantid | length |
+------------+--------------+--------+
|          1 |            1 |      0 |
|          1 |            2 |      0 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After I issue the update statement, to update post.id to 20:

```
mysql> UPDATE `post` SET `id` = '20' WHERE `post`.`id` =2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from post_path;
+------------+--------------+--------+
| ancestorid | descendantid | length |
+------------+--------------+--------+
|          1 |            1 |      0 |
|          1 |           20 |      0 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice that the ancestorid is still 1, this appears to be an issue with [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html):

> If you use a multiple-table UPDATE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, update a single table and rely on the ON UPDATE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly. See Section 14.3.5.4, “InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints”.

The reason why your first query is failing, is because ancestorid is not updating to 10, but descendantid is, and because you are trying to set post.id to 10, and ancestorid in post_path table is still referencing the value 1, which would no longer exist.

You should consider altering your schema to avoid this, and to also avoid updating an auto_increment column so you avoid collisions.

Comment: when i update to 10, both ancestorid and descendantid must be changed in the same time. the reason you said is not reasonable.

Comment: What I am saying is, I don't think it's possible for MySQL to update both at the same time. In my test cases I was unable to get both to change.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, because of explaining details. but i Don't know why MySql can not change both same foreign key in one row!!! this seems it is a bug must be reported to MySql website.

Comment: You can have multiple FKS, and they will change their respective values based on FK value, but it doesn't appear that you can have multiple FKs linking to the same source column and expect it to work consistently due to optimizer.

Comment: Interesting, testing the schema beforehand with this in mind removed a headache, thx

Comment: @ahoo I'm having the same issue with MySQL, did you find a solution or workaround for this over the last years?

Comment: @IvanRF I dont find any solution yet, although i havent tested over the last years.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution to your problem is to remove **descendantid** as a constraint and use a trigger to perform an update on the field.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER post_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE post_path SET post_path.descendantid = NEW.id WHERE post_path.descendantid = OLD.id
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why the second one worked is that you have kept different values for `ancestorid` and `descendantid`. When you are making two different constraints on the basis of a change on a particular attributes. only the first constraint will work, not the second one. Which is the case in your first update try.

Comment: Mysql must satisfies both constraints simultaneously, Not serially one and then other one. because both constraints is basis of only one attribute. is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first update fails and second does not is because in the second instance your ancestorid and descendantid reference different rows in your post table,

```
ancestorid   = 1
descendantid = 2
```

The first update fails when it attempts to update post_path.ancestorid as in doing so the constraint between post.id and post_path.descendantid fails as these values would no longer match (1 !== 10).

Assuming that any given post cannot be both an ancestor and a descendant then the issue here is only in the execution of the first insert:

```
INSERT INTO `post_path` (`ancestorid` ,`descendantid` ,`length`) VALUES (1, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Mysql must satisfies both constraints simultaneously, Not serially one and then other one. because both constraints is basis of only one attribute.